# How to communicate between javascript modules

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've got a web page backed by some knockoutjs through to cloud kit and it's working well. I want to enhance what I have by adding infinite scroll (and thus get more data from the database etc.). What I do not yet understand is now to structure the program to maybe communicate between java script modules. This is best explained with example code:

```
window.addEventListener('cloudkitloaded', function() {
    // .
    // .
    // .
    ko.applyBindings(new TrafficCamNZViewModel());                    
});
```

and this

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event)
{
    var element = event.target;

    if (element.activeElement.scrollTop + element.body.clientHeight > document.height - 100)
    {
        console.log('We\'re near rock bottom');
    }
});
```

So this allows me to detect the web page scrolling and hitting the bottom.
How do I tell the cloud kit module that it needs to do something?

Comment: Are these all in the same JS file?  Are you using a module loader of any kind?

Comment: yes. all in the same JS file. What you see is it... apart from whats inside the cloud kit module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me treat your question as you've tagged it (with knockoutjs and not cloudkit). The Knockout part of this is relatively simple.

The option you have (just adding an event listener for scrolling) *can* work, certainly in this particular case, though typically you use an binding handler for it:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.onScroll = function(data, evt) {
    // here you have access to the relevant view model, as
    // well as the original event, and you can inform cloud
    // kit that it should further scroll
    console.log("Scrolling...");
  };
  
  self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
}

var vm = new ViewModel();

for (var i=0; i<25; i++) { vm.items.push(i); } // dummy data

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
div { height: 100px; background: snow; overflow-y: scroll; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="event: { scroll: onScroll }">
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

(Stack Snippets seem to have some sandbox/security issues with using the `evt` so can't complete the entire demo; left as an exercise for the reader.)

If the DOM interaction bit gets heavy, or you want to reuse it in places, I suggest not placing it in the view model but instead creating [a custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) for it.

As far as Cloudkit goes... I'm not sure, I'm not familiar with that library. You can either rewrite your current question slightly to be completely about the KnockoutJS part only and ask a second one on cloudkit. Or, you can rewrite (and most importantly: retag) your current question to more clearly ask about the Cloudkit part (include what you've tried/researched on that lib!), thus partially invalidating my answer (so ping me in a comment if you choose this option so I can decide whether to delete my answer or not).

Comment: Thank you. I've got it working (for now... need more work later). You are correct, cloud kit is my data delivery mechanism. The real juice here is knockoutjs. Once I've detected the scroll is near the bottom of my array, I'll fire off a message to cloud kit to get more data. I might see if I can move the overflow-y: scroll; to the page, rather than the div as in this form it makes the user experience inconsistent...   This is great - I can move on! Thank you so much.

Comment: The "forced" overflow css on the div was merely to demo in a Stack Snippet, because you cannot easily put a `data-bind` on the `body` in them. Glad to hear my post helped.

Comment: Certainly has. I've got it implemented. Successfully detected the bottom of the scroll and have planned what I'll do next for the data fetching. Thank you Jeroen. What a great community!